# How to model this relationship in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm try to build up a model and am struggling with how to handle a particular relation. There are two objects; Person, with name, email address, etc. and Sport, with name, location, etc.

The relation I have is a separate object that maps players to sports. There is an additional field for player info specific to the sport. I want to have another relationship that specifies an (optional) person that is a proxy for the player for a sport.

The proxy would be so that the specified person would be able to act as the player (possibly for some limited time). For example, let's say player A was administering Soccer and was going on vacation for two weeks. They would want one person to act on their behalf, sending notices, notifying other players of games, etc.

In SQL, I'd have a table with a `player_id`, a `sport_id`, and another `player_id` field, which could be null (and an expiration date, and other fields).

I can't seem to figure out how to specify this in a Django model however. Here's what I have so far:

```
"""Indicates people who are registered for a type of event.

They can have a unique nickname for each event, if desired.
In addition, they can select a proxy for them, who can act in
thier behalf for this event."""

nickname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
event_type = models.ForeignKey(EventType, related_name='+')
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='+')
proxy = models.OneToOneField(Person, related_name='+') # ?????
proxy_expires = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

This seems to make the proxy a required field, which is not what I want. Any suggestions on how I model this with the constrains of the proxy being optional, one proxy per person per sport.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does adding `blank=True` (and probably `null=True`) not do the job?

Comment: It does work for the *proxy_expires* field (which is just a normal field, but it does *not* work for the *proxy* field, which is the relation I'm having a problem with. That field ends up as a "UNIQUE" key field.

Comment: The OneToOne field is conceptually a ForeignKey with unique=True as described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield. You should probably create it as a ForeignKey with null=True and blank=True and don't forget to set the related_name

Comment: Looks like that was it. I needed both **null** and **blank** set, in addition to using **ForeignKey**, so that it could be optional.